# Netlify configuration for custom email domain with EmailJS

Tags: reactjs, email, netlify

I’m building a project in React where I have a contact page that sends email to my custom domain email, I already have a domain and email with that domain that I want to send the forms to it.

When I had my personal gmail configured via EmailJS,it worked perfectly when I changed it to the one that I bought I tried to set it up via 365outlook but it didn’t work, it doesn’t send emails anymore as like I don’t have « permission «

So I want to try via SMTP Server configurations from Netlify with EmailJS but can’t find any of these yet if Netlify supports it.

Does Netlify support it? If not how can I use my custom domain with third party email service like EmailJS, what are my options?

Tried to by default EmailJS outlook settings but it couldn’t send emails